# Laravel Eloquent JOIN() with primitive data type causes errors

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel. This query works perfectly:

```
    $pageslugs = DB::table('page_slugs AS pslug')
      ->select(explode(',','pslug.page_id,pslug.slug,dslug.slug AS default_slug'))
      ->join('page_slugs AS dslug',function($join){
        $join->on('dslug.page_id','=','pslug.page_id');
        //$join->on('dslug.locale','=',DB::raw('en'));
        //$join->on('dslug.locale','=','en');
        $join->on('dslug.active','=',DB::raw(1));
      })
      ->whereIn('pslug.page_id',Arr::pluck($menupages,'page_id'))
      ->where([['pslug.active','=',1],['pslug.locale','=',$lang],['dslug.locale','=',app('config')->get('app.locale')]])
      ->get()
      ->toArray();
```

But if I uncomment either of the `$join->on('dslug.locale','=',DB::raw('en'));` or `$join->on('dslug.locale','=','en');`, Then I get the error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column &#039;en&#039; in &#039;on clause&#039; (SQL: select `pslug`.`page_id`, `pslug`.`slug`, `dslug`.`slug` as `default_slug` from `page_slugs` as `pslug` inner join `page_slugs` as `dslug` on `dslug`.`page_id` = `pslug`.`page_id` and `dslug`.`locale` = en and `dslug`.`active` = 1 where `pslug`.`page_id` in (19, 21, 11, 18, 22, 12, 13, 16, 14, 15, 17) and (`pslug`.`active` = 1 and `pslug`.`locale` = en and `dslug`.`locale` = en)) in file /var/www/john.project.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php on line 664
```

How do you do a join against a primitive data type in Laravel?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You can't join on a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you are trying to add extra filters to the join clause. This can be done by just adding where clauses to your join:

```
->join('page_slugs AS dslug', function ($join) {
    $join->on('dslug.page_id', '=', 'pslug.page_id')
        ->where('dslug.locale', 'en')
        ->where('dslug.active', true);
})
```